# Declare an object of generic shape in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype, static-typing

Consider a function:

```
const f = k => v => array =>
  array.reduce(
    (total, current) => ({
      ...total,
      [current[k]]: current[v]
    }),
    {}
  );
```

This function takes key `k`, value `v`, and then an array of objects as input, and returns a map-like object where keys and values are taken from the values of key `k` and value `v`. For example,

```
const k = 'key';
const v = 'value';
const input = [{ key: 1, value: 100 }, { key: 2, value: 200 }, { key: 3, value: 300 }];

f(k)(v)(input); // -> { '1': 100, '2': 200, '3': 300 }
```

I'm struggling to declare type of objects in array. They have to have two properties, but these properties are not static. Still, they can be derived from `k` and `v` preceding the `array`. Every object in the `array` should have shape like

```
const k = 'key';
const v = 'value';
{ [k]: 123, [v]: 456 }; // -> { 'key': 123, 'value': 456 }
```

So far I'm at this point:

```
const f = <K>(k: K) => <V>(v: V) => (array: Array<{ [k]: K, [v]: V }>) =>
  array.reduce(
    (total, current) => ({
      ...total,
      [current[k]]: current[v]
    }),
    {}
  );
```

which is technically valid Flow syntax but is giving me an error:

```
1: const f = <K>(k: K) => <V>(v: V) => (array: Array<{ [k]: K, [v]: V }>) =>
                                                        ^ Cannot use `K` as a type because `K` is a value. To get the type of a value use `typeof`
```

How do I declare a type that is an object of shape derived from previously declared generic types? Is this possible in Flow?

Answer (score 0):

The `{ [...]: ... }` syntax in Flow does not mean the same thing as it does in ES6. `{ [k]: K, [v]: V }` does not mean that the object must have a key `k` of type `K` and a key `v` of type `V`. Instead, the syntax is used to denote an [indexer property in Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps). Thus, `{ [k]: K, [v]: V }` is invalid since you may only specify a single indexer property. However, lets say we only had `{ [k]: K }`. This still wouldn't work as intended because this would represent the type "an object with keys of type `k` that map to values of type `K`."

Unfortunately, I don't think Flow currently supports what you are trying to do. I believe this type would fall under [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which is not supported by Flow at the moment, since the type of the array depends on the values of `k` and `v`.